# Non-Hermitian Hamiltonians with just $\mathcal{T}$ symmetry

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, parity, time-reversal-symmetry

I apologise in advance if this is a trivial or nonsensical question. I am not very familiar with this area.

In the introduction to non-Hermitian Hamiltonians [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0501052), on page 7 (equations 8 and 9), the author shows that if:

1. $[H, \mathcal{P}\mathcal{T}] = 0$
2. $H$ and $\mathcal{P}\mathcal{T}$ have simultaneous eigenstates even though $ \mathcal{P}\mathcal{T}$ is antilinear.

Then, (1) and (2) imply that the spectrum of $H$ is real. This is because, if,
$$H|\phi\rangle = E|\phi\rangle; \  \mathcal{P}\mathcal{T}|\phi\rangle = \lambda|\phi\rangle$$
Then, as $\mathcal{T}\alpha \ = \ \alpha^{*}\mathcal{T}$ ($\alpha$ is a complex number),
$$[H, \mathcal{P}\mathcal{T}] = 0 \ \Rightarrow \  \lambda E \ = \ E^{*} \lambda$$
Which means that $E$ is real (the author's argument is a bit different).

The problem is that the same argument (whether the one above or the one in the manuscript) that lead to this conclusion also work for just the time reversal operator, $\mathcal{T}$. So, shouldn't such non Hermitian Hamiltonians that have a real spectrum include (more generally) the class of Hamiltonians with just the $\mathcal{T}$ symmetry with $\mathcal{P}\mathcal{T}$ symmetric ones being a smaller subset of them?